# EmberJS: dynamic ids in action calls

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Maybe I'm getting at this the wrong way. I have a view with a list that gets populated dynamically, each list element has an

```
{{action add}}
```

in it. The add-action pushes the clicked element into a store.

```
actions: {
    add: function(product) {
        App.Item.store.push('item', {id:1,product: product.name})
    }
}
```

My problem is the id. I need a dynamic id here or else the items get pushed into the same position and only the last pushed item is in the store. I thought about adding a counting-variable which gets increased every time the action is called and then used for the id but
a) I'm not quite sure how to do this and
b) this feels wrong somehow but I didn't find a better solution so far. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Just to be clear this isn't using ember-data right?

Comment: No, I just want to push records like in this example http://emberjs.com/guides/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/ but I need to specify an Id for doing so.

Comment: That example you linked to is actually using ember-data.  In ember-data you use push to preload records into the store which requires already knowing the id of the record (i.e., the record already exists on the server side).  In your case it looks like you're trying to push a new record into the store which won't work as you don't have an id yet.  Instead you would need to save the record and have the server return back what the id should be for that record.  It's a bit confusing but the ember getting started guide which you linked to is in fact using ember-data.

Comment: Hm, okay, then this isn't what I need since I only want to store chosen items from a list and show them in a "shopping cart" kind of way. How would I save this then? With fixtures I need an id, too, if I use pushObject.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused by your use case.  Is this just for learning ember or are you using it in an actual application?  If the items need ids you will need to assign the ids somehow (probably from some data store that keeps track of all the available items and their ids).  If you use fixtures you can just make up the ids yourself in the fixture data.  Are you able to provide a jsbin or fiddle of what you have so far?

Comment: I'm getting started with ember and try to rebuild an actual application. If I push something into a fixture, I need to provide an id, correct? So I could either read out the highest id in the fixture, increase it by 1 and push the next item into it or I could use some kind of global counter maybe?!

Comment: Fixtures are supposed to work similar to how you would use ember-data with an actual data persistence store.  So instead of using this.store.push() you need to create a new record and then call save on it.  I would look over the todo example on the ember site as it will cover most of what you're trying to do with Fixtures.  Here's the link to how to create a new record: http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/creating-a-new-model/  (You'll want to start from the beginning of the guide though so it all makes sense)

Comment: IMO, if you are going to use Ember in an application, most likely you will be dealing with persistent objects. You might want to have a look at functions like createRecord(), save(), find() and delete() / destory() in order to perform the persistent changes in you data. The most imp task as a beginner would be to understand how template is backed up by a model and a controller. I hope you would enjoy learning emebr.